# Cannot get access to Marionette module from app.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, marionette

I am currently working my way through David Sulc's excellent "Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle Introduction" and have come unstuck at modules. With the app as it currently stands I am trying to access an API in a module called 'contacts.js' from the index.html script but I get the following error when I try to run the app:

```
"Handler not found for 'contact: entities' "
```

I am able to hit the API directly from the console in Chrome and manually get the 'contact' information so I was thinking this was a loading sequence problem where the API might not be available by the time app.js loads, however the loading sequence is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor/json2.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor/backbone.marionette.min.js"></script>
```

then the local scripts as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/entities/contact.js"></script>
```

and a script tag below the last two script tags directly runs the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
... some view code
ContactManager.on("initialize:after", function(){
    var contacts = ContactManager.request("contact: entities");
... some more code
</script>
```

the line beginning var contacts = ..... is the one giving me the error. Any help appreciated

I am as certain as I can be that I have scripted this exactly as per the book.

Comment: Could it be the space between "contact:" and "entities"?

Comment: You're exactly right net.uk.sweet. That's what it was. Tired eyes... so used to typing out JS name value pairs that I did it on autopilot and then couldn't even see it as an error! Can't mark a comment as the correct answer, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Added an answer so you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space in your event name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
... some view code
ContactManager.on("initialize:after", function(){
    // Remove the space in contact: entities -->
    var contacts = ContactManager.request("contact: entities");
... some more code
</script>
```